# Google App Script Cache data type and how to convert to string

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

```
function receiveText(form){//code that text is received and saved
  var nameBox = form.text;
  //Logger.log(nameBox);
  var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();
  cache.put("text",nameBox);
}
function items() {//compare and put out the text
   var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();
  //cache.put("text","hello");
   var exmp =cache.get("text");
   var x=String(exmp);
   if(x=="hello")
   return( "Password correct" );
   else return x;

   }

<HTML>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
<p id="demo"></p>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" value=" " name="text" />
        <input type="button" onClick="formSubmit()" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formSubmit() {
        google.script.run.receiveText(document.forms[0]);
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessed).items();
    }          
function onSuccessed(items) {
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = items;
   }
</script>
</html>
```

I'm writing in google app script! I can never hit the (x=="hello") block in items can anyone help me, even tho the value of x will return hello but i don't know in what type.
Basically, it's a textbox that I will store information to the cache when the button a button is clicked. Then, it will run the next function of taking from the cache and processing the information. It's strange cause I can force my cache to be hello and the x will be equal to hello and will return Password correct and it works with numbers too but not strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the type of value which is retrieved is a string.

How about this answer? It supposes that "hello" is inputted to the text box. In this case, when the length `form.text` of `receiveText(form)` is retrieved, the length is 6. The length of "hello" is 5. Each character code is `[32,104,101,108,108,111]`. Namely, the top letter is a space. By this, `if(x=="hello")` is always false. In order to remove this issue using your script, please modify for `receiveText(form)` as follows.

#### From :

```
var nameBox = form.text;
```

#### To :

```
var nameBox = form.text.trim();
```

#### Note :

- I think that there are several solutions for your situation, so please think of this as one of them.
- Since google.script.run is the asynchronous, when you get the value from CacheService after you put the value, the following script might be better. About this, please select for your situation.

Sample

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessed).items();
}).receiveText(document.forms[0]);
```

#### Reference :

- [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)
- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)